# How to Trigger an update of the QTreeView after adjusting the Geometry after undocking

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.7, qtreeview

**Using :** Python 3.7  pyqt5  Windows10

When undocking I resize the main window to be the size it would have been without the DockWindow but in doing so the right two columns disappear out of view.  I have tried various events to try and trigger an adjustment to that TreeView but to no avail. The code I have included has the issue just click one of the Docks and then detach the resulting window from the Main Window and you can see what I mean. As always any help is greatly appreciated.

I have tried the following:

```py
self.updateGeometry()
self.CenterPane.updateGeometry()
self.CenterPane.ItemDsply.updateGeometry()

self.resizeEvent(QResizeEvent(self.size(), QSize()))
self.CenterPane.resizeEvent(QResizeEvent(self.size(), QSize()))
self.CenterPane.ItemDsply.resizeEvent(QResizeEvent(self.size(), QSize()))
```

Here is a working example:

```py
from sys  import exit as sysExit
from math import trunc

from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class CustomItemModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.ForegroundRole:
            brush = QBrush()
            brush.setColor(Qt.blue)
            brush.setStyle(Qt.SolidPattern)
            return brush

        elif role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            brush = QBrush()
            brush.setColor(Qt.yellow)
            brush.setStyle(Qt.SolidPattern)
            return brush

        elif role == Qt.FontRole:
            font = QFont()
            font.setBold(True)
            font.setPointSize(10)
            return font

        return super().headerData(section, orientation, role)

class DockWin1(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QDockWidget.__init__(self)

        self.setWindowTitle('Dock 1')
        self.MainWin = parent

        self.container = QWidget(self)
        self.container.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())
        self.setWidget(self.container)
        self.container.layout().addWidget(QTextEdit())
        self.setMinimumWidth(100)
        self.setMinimumHeight(100)

        self.topLevelChanged.connect(self.SetDock1Free)

    @property
    def MainWin(self):
        return self.__parent

    @MainWin.setter
    def MainWin(self, value):
        self.__parent = value

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.MainWin.ClosingDock1()

    def SetDock1Free(self):
        if self.MainWin.Dock1Free:
            self.MainWin.CheckToResize('Dock1', 100)
        else:
            self.MainWin.CheckToResize('Dock1', self.width())

        self.MainWin.Dock1Free = not self.MainWin.Dock1Free

class DockWin2(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QDockWidget.__init__(self)

        self.setWindowTitle('Dock 2')
        self.MainWin = parent

        self.container = QWidget(self)
        self.container.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())
        self.setWidget(self.container)
        self.container.layout().addWidget(QTextEdit())
        self.setMinimumWidth(100)
        self.setMinimumHeight(100)

        self.topLevelChanged.connect(self.SetDock2Free)

    @property
    def MainWin(self):
        return self.__parent

    @MainWin.setter
    def MainWin(self, value):
        self.__parent = value

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.MainWin.ClosingDock2()

    def SetDock2Free(self):
        if self.MainWin.Dock2Free:
            self.MainWin.CheckToResize('Dock2', 100)
        else:
            self.MainWin.CheckToResize('Dock2', self.width())

        self.MainWin.Dock2Free = not self.MainWin.Dock2Free

class ItemDsplyr(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, CentrPane):
        QTreeView.__init__(self, CentrPane)
        self.CntrPane = CentrPane

        self.setEditTriggers(QTreeView().NoEditTriggers)
        self.model = CustomItemModel(0, 3)
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['1st Col', '2nd Col', '3rd Col'])
        self.model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, Qt.AlignCenter, Qt.TextAlignmentRole)
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.setMinimumWidth(250)

        self.header().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.header().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.setColumnWidth(1, 75)
        self.setColumnWidth(2, 100)

class CenterPanel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, MainWin):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.MyEditor = QTextEdit('Editorial')
        self.ItemDsply = ItemDsplyr(self)

        CntrPane = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        CntrPane.addWidget(self.MyEditor)
        CntrPane.addWidget(self.ItemDsply)
        CntrPane.setSizes([50,200])
        CntrPane.setCollapsible(0, False)
        CntrPane.setCollapsible(1, False)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(CntrPane)

        self.setLayout(hbox)

class MenuToolBar(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, MainWin):
        QDockWidget.__init__(self)
        self.MainWin = MainWin
        self.MainMenu = MainWin.menuBar()

        self.WndowMenu  = self.MainMenu.addMenu('Windows')

        self.Dock1Act = QAction('Dock1', self)
        self.Dock1Act.setStatusTip('Open the Dock1 Window')
        self.Dock1Act.triggered.connect(MainWin.ShowDock1)

        self.Dock2Act = QAction('Dock2', self)
        self.Dock2Act.setStatusTip('Open the Dock2 Window')
        self.Dock2Act.triggered.connect(MainWin.ShowDock2)

        self.WndowMenu.addAction(self.Dock1Act)
        self.WndowMenu.addSeparator()
        self.WndowMenu.addAction(self.Dock2Act)

        self.InitToolBar(MainWin)

    def InitToolBar(self, MainWin):
        self.mainToolBar = MainWin.addToolBar("Quick Access")

        self.mainToolBar.addAction(self.Dock1Act)
        self.mainToolBar.addSeparator()
        self.mainToolBar.addAction(self.Dock2Act)

class UI_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, MainDesktop):
        super(UI_MainWindow, self).__init__(MainDesktop)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
        self.Dock1Open = False
        self.Dock1Free = False
        self.Dock2Open = False
        self.Dock2Free = False

        self.MnDskTop = MainDesktop

      # Left, Top, Width, Height
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 550, 550)

        self.CenterPane = CenterPanel(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.CenterPane)

        self.MenuToolBar = MenuToolBar(self)

    def ShowDock1(self):
        if not self.Dock1Open:
            self.CheckToResize('Dock1', 300)
            self.Dock1 = DockWin1(self)
            self.Dock1Open = True
            self.Dock1Free = False
            self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.Dock1)

    def ClosingDock1(self):
        self.Dock1Open = False

    def ShowDock2(self):
        if not self.Dock2Open:
            self.CheckToResize('Dock2', 300)
            self.Dock2 = DockWin2(self)
            self.Dock2Open = True
            self.Dock2Free = False
            self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.Dock2)

    def ClosingDock2(self):
        self.Dock2Open = False

    def CheckToResize(self, WinDocked, DockWdth):
      # If any of the other docks are open and docked do not resize
        if   self.Dock1Open and WinDocked != 'Dock1' and not self.Dock1Free:
            return
        elif self.Dock2Open and WinDocked != 'Dock2' and not self.Dock2Free:
            return

        Docking = True
        if   WinDocked == 'Dock1' and self.Dock1Open != self.Dock1Free:
            Docking = False
        elif WinDocked == 'Dock2'  and self.Dock2Open != self.Dock2Free:
            Docking = False

        WinLeft  = self.geometry().left()
        WinTop   = self.geometry().top()
        WinWidth = self.geometry().width()
        WinHight = self.geometry().height()
        ScrWidth = self.MnDskTop.screenGeometry().width()

      # Docking
        if Docking:
            if ScrWidth < (WinLeft + WinWidth + DockWdth):
                WinLeft  = 0
                WinWidth = ScrWidth
            elif WinLeft > (trunc(DockWdth/2)):
                WinLeft = WinLeft - trunc(DockWdth/2)
                WinWidth = WinWidth + DockWdth
            else:
                WinLeft = 0
                WinWidth = WinWidth + DockWdth

            self.setGeometry(WinLeft, WinTop, WinWidth, WinHight)
     # Un-Docking
        else:
            WinWidth = WinWidth - DockWdth
            self.setGeometry(WinLeft, WinTop, WinWidth, WinHight)
          # Call the Event that Triggers View Adjustment ?? 
            self.CenterPane.ItemDsply.updateGeometry()
#            self.CenterPane.ItemDsply.resizeEvent(QResizeEvent(self.size(), QSize()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp = QApplication([])

    MainGui = UI_MainWindow(MainApp.desktop())
    MainGui.show()

    sysExit(MainApp.exec_())
```

As stated I am trying to get the QTreeView to adjust appropriately to the newly sized window so that it shows all three columns.  Currently it shoves the last to columns out of view.

**Requested Images:** (see comments)

[image: DockWidget Attached]
[image: Immediately After Detaching]
[image: After Tweaking the Main Window a Smidge]

Comment: You could place images of the problem, I have tested your code in Linux with PyQt5 5.12.2 and did not observe the problem

Comment: Images added at bottom - and system specifics added at top

Comment: Okay adjusted the images 1st ) after clicking the dock button  2nd ) Immediately after Undocking  3rd ) After tweaking the size of the main window just a smidge --- Note I am assuming that Tweak triggers some event that adjusts the main window accordingly that is what I am trying to do via code as it fixes the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it ended up actually being a combination of things first as @S. Nick stated (above)

```
self.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
```

needed to be added to the ItemDsplyr class

However something still needed to trigger the resizing as it does not always fire when the Dock Window is detached when using setGeometry() so I replaced setGeometry() with resize() as follows:

```
WinWidth = WinWidth - DockWdth
self.resize(WinWidth, WinHight)
```

Note had I needed to reposition the window upon undocking then I would just need to call setGeometry() followed by the resize() for it appears the resize() is what triggers the repaint functionality

Answer (score 1):

> void QHeaderView::setSectionResizeMode(int logicalIndex, QHeaderView::ResizeMode mode)
>
> Sets the constraints on how the section specified by logicalIndex in the header can be resized to those described by the given mode. The logical index should exist at the time this function is called.

```
from sys  import exit as sysExit
from math import trunc

from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class CustomItemModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.ForegroundRole:
            brush = QBrush()
            brush.setColor(Qt.blue)
            brush.setStyle(Qt.SolidPattern)
            return brush

        elif role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            brush = QBrush()
            brush.setColor(Qt.yellow)
            brush.setStyle(Qt.SolidPattern)
            return brush

        elif role == Qt.FontRole:
            font = QFont()
            font.setBold(True)
            font.setPointSize(10)
            return font

        return super().headerData(section, orientation, role)

class DockWin1(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QDockWidget.__init__(self)

        self.setWindowTitle('Dock 1')
        self.MainWin = parent

        self.container = QWidget(self)
        self.container.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())
        self.setWidget(self.container)
        self.container.layout().addWidget(QTextEdit())
        self.setMinimumWidth(100)
        self.setMinimumHeight(100)

        self.topLevelChanged.connect(self.SetDock1Free)

    @property
    def MainWin(self):
        return self.__parent

    @MainWin.setter
    def MainWin(self, value):
        self.__parent = value

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.MainWin.ClosingDock1()

    def SetDock1Free(self):
        if self.MainWin.Dock1Free:
            self.MainWin.CheckToResize('Dock1', 100)
        else:
            self.MainWin.CheckToResize('Dock1', self.width())

        self.MainWin.Dock1Free = not self.MainWin.Dock1Free

class DockWin2(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QDockWidget.__init__(self)

        self.setWindowTitle('Dock 2')
        self.MainWin = parent

        self.container = QWidget(self)
        self.container.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())
        self.setWidget(self.container)
        self.container.layout().addWidget(QTextEdit())
        self.setMinimumWidth(100)
        self.setMinimumHeight(100)

        self.topLevelChanged.connect(self.SetDock2Free)

    @property
    def MainWin(self):
        return self.__parent

    @MainWin.setter
    def MainWin(self, value):
        self.__parent = value

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.MainWin.ClosingDock2()

    def SetDock2Free(self):
        if self.MainWin.Dock2Free:
            self.MainWin.CheckToResize('Dock2', 100)
        else:
            self.MainWin.CheckToResize('Dock2', self.width())

        self.MainWin.Dock2Free = not self.MainWin.Dock2Free

class ItemDsplyr(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, CentrPane):
        QTreeView.__init__(self, CentrPane)
        self.CntrPane = CentrPane

        self.setEditTriggers(QTreeView().NoEditTriggers)
        self.model = CustomItemModel(0, 3)
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['1st Col', '2nd Col', '3rd Col'])
        self.model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, Qt.AlignCenter, Qt.TextAlignmentRole)
        
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.setMinimumWidth(250)

        self.header().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.header().setSectionResizeMode(2, QHeaderView.Stretch)               # <---------
        self.setColumnWidth(1, 75)
        self.setColumnWidth(2, 100)

class CenterPanel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, MainWin):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.MyEditor = QTextEdit('Editorial')
        self.ItemDsply = ItemDsplyr(self)

        CntrPane = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        CntrPane.addWidget(self.MyEditor)
        CntrPane.addWidget(self.ItemDsply)
        CntrPane.setSizes([50,200])
        CntrPane.setCollapsible(0, False)
        CntrPane.setCollapsible(1, False)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(CntrPane)

        self.setLayout(hbox)

class MenuToolBar(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, MainWin):
        QDockWidget.__init__(self)
        self.MainWin = MainWin
        self.MainMenu = MainWin.menuBar()

        self.WndowMenu  = self.MainMenu.addMenu('Windows')

        self.Dock1Act = QAction('Dock1', self)
        self.Dock1Act.setStatusTip('Open the Dock1 Window')
        self.Dock1Act.triggered.connect(MainWin.ShowDock1)

        self.Dock2Act = QAction('Dock2', self)
        self.Dock2Act.setStatusTip('Open the Dock2 Window')
        self.Dock2Act.triggered.connect(MainWin.ShowDock2)

        self.WndowMenu.addAction(self.Dock1Act)
        self.WndowMenu.addSeparator()
        self.WndowMenu.addAction(self.Dock2Act)

        self.InitToolBar(MainWin)

    def InitToolBar(self, MainWin):
        self.mainToolBar = MainWin.addToolBar("Quick Access")

        self.mainToolBar.addAction(self.Dock1Act)
        self.mainToolBar.addSeparator()
        self.mainToolBar.addAction(self.Dock2Act)

class UI_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, MainDesktop):
        super(UI_MainWindow, self).__init__(MainDesktop)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
        self.Dock1Open = False
        self.Dock1Free = False
        self.Dock2Open = False
        self.Dock2Free = False

        self.MnDskTop = MainDesktop
        print(f"MainDesktop->{MainDesktop}")

      # Left, Top, Width, Height
        self.setGeometry(200, 100, 550, 550)

        self.CenterPane = CenterPanel(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.CenterPane)

        self.MenuToolBar = MenuToolBar(self)

    def ShowDock1(self):
        if not self.Dock1Open:
            self.CheckToResize('Dock1', 300)
            self.Dock1 = DockWin1(self)
            self.Dock1Open = True
            self.Dock1Free = False
            self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.Dock1)

    def ClosingDock1(self):
        self.Dock1Open = False

    def ShowDock2(self):
        if not self.Dock2Open:
            self.CheckToResize('Dock2', 300)
            self.Dock2 = DockWin2(self)
            self.Dock2Open = True
            self.Dock2Free = False
            self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.Dock2)

    def ClosingDock2(self):
        self.Dock2Open = False

    def CheckToResize(self, WinDocked, DockWdth):
      # If any of the other docks are open and docked do not resize
        if   self.Dock1Open and WinDocked != 'Dock1' and not self.Dock1Free:
            return
        elif self.Dock2Open and WinDocked != 'Dock2' and not self.Dock2Free:
            return

        Docking = True
        if   WinDocked == 'Dock1' and self.Dock1Open != self.Dock1Free:
            Docking = False
        elif WinDocked == 'Dock2'  and self.Dock2Open != self.Dock2Free:
            Docking = False

        WinLeft  = self.geometry().left()
        WinTop   = self.geometry().top()
        WinWidth = self.geometry().width()
        WinHight = self.geometry().height()
        ScrWidth = self.MnDskTop.screenGeometry().width()

      # Docking
        if Docking:
            if ScrWidth < (WinLeft + WinWidth + DockWdth):
                WinLeft  = 0
                WinWidth = ScrWidth
            elif WinLeft > (trunc(DockWdth/2)):
                WinLeft = WinLeft - trunc(DockWdth/2)
                WinWidth = WinWidth + DockWdth
            else:
                WinLeft = 0
                WinWidth = WinWidth + DockWdth

            self.setGeometry(WinLeft, WinTop, WinWidth, WinHight)
     # Un-Docking
        else:
            WinWidth = WinWidth - DockWdth
            self.setGeometry(WinLeft, WinTop, WinWidth, WinHight)
          # Call the Event that Triggers View Adjustment ?? 
            self.CenterPane.ItemDsply.updateGeometry()
#            self.CenterPane.ItemDsply.resizeEvent(QResizeEvent(self.size(), QSize()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp = QApplication([])

    MainGui = UI_MainWindow(MainApp.desktop())
    MainGui.show()

    sysExit(MainApp.exec_())
```

[image]

---

**Update**

> sizeAdjustPolicy : SizeAdjustPolicy
>
> This property holds the policy describing how the size of the scroll area changes when the size of the viewport changes.

```
from sys  import exit as sysExit
from math import trunc

from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class CustomItemModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.ForegroundRole:
            brush = QBrush()
            brush.setColor(Qt.blue)
            brush.setStyle(Qt.SolidPattern)
            return brush

        elif role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            brush = QBrush()
            brush.setColor(Qt.yellow)
            brush.setStyle(Qt.SolidPattern)
            return brush

        elif role == Qt.FontRole:
            font = QFont()
            font.setBold(True)
            font.setPointSize(10)
            return font

        return super().headerData(section, orientation, role)

class DockWin1(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QDockWidget.__init__(self)

        self.setWindowTitle('Dock 1')
        self.MainWin = parent

        self.container = QWidget(self)
        self.container.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())
        self.setWidget(self.container)
        self.container.layout().addWidget(QTextEdit())
        self.setMinimumWidth(100)
        self.setMinimumHeight(100)

        self.topLevelChanged.connect(self.SetDock1Free)

    @property
    def MainWin(self):
        return self.__parent

    @MainWin.setter
    def MainWin(self, value):
        self.__parent = value

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.MainWin.ClosingDock1()

    def SetDock1Free(self):
        if self.MainWin.Dock1Free:
            self.MainWin.CheckToResize('Dock1', 100)
        else:
            self.MainWin.CheckToResize('Dock1', self.width())

        self.MainWin.Dock1Free = not self.MainWin.Dock1Free

class DockWin2(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QDockWidget.__init__(self)

        self.setWindowTitle('Dock 2')
        self.MainWin = parent

        self.container = QWidget(self)
        self.container.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())
        self.setWidget(self.container)
        self.container.layout().addWidget(QTextEdit())
        self.setMinimumWidth(100)
        self.setMinimumHeight(100)

        self.topLevelChanged.connect(self.SetDock2Free)

    @property
    def MainWin(self):
        return self.__parent

    @MainWin.setter
    def MainWin(self, value):
        self.__parent = value

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.MainWin.ClosingDock2()

    def SetDock2Free(self):
        if self.MainWin.Dock2Free:
            self.MainWin.CheckToResize('Dock2', 100)
        else:
            self.MainWin.CheckToResize('Dock2', self.width())

        self.MainWin.Dock2Free = not self.MainWin.Dock2Free

class ItemDsplyr(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, CentrPane):
        QTreeView.__init__(self, CentrPane)
        self.CntrPane = CentrPane

        self.setEditTriggers(QTreeView().NoEditTriggers)
        self.model = CustomItemModel(0, 3)
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['1st Col', '2nd Col', '3rd Col'])
        self.model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, Qt.AlignCenter, Qt.TextAlignmentRole)
        
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.setMinimumWidth(250)
        
        self.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)     # <<<========

        self.header().setStretchLastSection(False)   
        self.header().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.Stretch)               
        
        self.setColumnWidth(1, 75)
        self.setColumnWidth(2, 100)   

class CenterPanel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, MainWin):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.MyEditor = QTextEdit('Editorial')
        self.ItemDsply = ItemDsplyr(self)

        CntrPane = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        CntrPane.addWidget(self.MyEditor)
        CntrPane.addWidget(self.ItemDsply)
        CntrPane.setSizes([50,200])
        CntrPane.setCollapsible(0, False)
        CntrPane.setCollapsible(1, False)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(CntrPane)

        self.setLayout(hbox)

class MenuToolBar(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, MainWin):
        QDockWidget.__init__(self)
        self.MainWin = MainWin
        self.MainMenu = MainWin.menuBar()

        self.WndowMenu  = self.MainMenu.addMenu('Windows')

        self.Dock1Act = QAction('Dock1', self)
        self.Dock1Act.setStatusTip('Open the Dock1 Window')
        self.Dock1Act.triggered.connect(MainWin.ShowDock1)

        self.Dock2Act = QAction('Dock2', self)
        self.Dock2Act.setStatusTip('Open the Dock2 Window')
        self.Dock2Act.triggered.connect(MainWin.ShowDock2)

        self.WndowMenu.addAction(self.Dock1Act)
        self.WndowMenu.addSeparator()
        self.WndowMenu.addAction(self.Dock2Act)

        self.InitToolBar(MainWin)

    def InitToolBar(self, MainWin):
        self.mainToolBar = MainWin.addToolBar("Quick Access")

        self.mainToolBar.addAction(self.Dock1Act)
        self.mainToolBar.addSeparator()
        self.mainToolBar.addAction(self.Dock2Act)

class UI_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, MainDesktop):
        super(UI_MainWindow, self).__init__(MainDesktop)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
        self.Dock1Open = False
        self.Dock1Free = False
        self.Dock2Open = False
        self.Dock2Free = False

        self.MnDskTop = MainDesktop
#        print(f"MainDesktop->{MainDesktop}")

      # Left, Top, Width, Height
        self.setGeometry(200, 100, 550, 550)

        self.CenterPane = CenterPanel(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.CenterPane)

        self.MenuToolBar = MenuToolBar(self)

    def ShowDock1(self):
        if not self.Dock1Open:
            self.CheckToResize('Dock1', 300)
            self.Dock1 = DockWin1(self)
            self.Dock1Open = True
            self.Dock1Free = False
            self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.Dock1)

    def ClosingDock1(self):
        self.Dock1Open = False

    def ShowDock2(self):
        if not self.Dock2Open:
            self.CheckToResize('Dock2', 300)
            self.Dock2 = DockWin2(self)
            self.Dock2Open = True
            self.Dock2Free = False
            self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.Dock2)

    def ClosingDock2(self):
        self.Dock2Open = False

    def CheckToResize(self, WinDocked, DockWdth):
      # If any of the other docks are open and docked do not resize
        if   self.Dock1Open and WinDocked != 'Dock1' and not self.Dock1Free:
            return
        elif self.Dock2Open and WinDocked != 'Dock2' and not self.Dock2Free:
            return

        Docking = True
        if   WinDocked == 'Dock1' and self.Dock1Open != self.Dock1Free:
            Docking = False
        elif WinDocked == 'Dock2'  and self.Dock2Open != self.Dock2Free:
            Docking = False

        WinLeft  = self.geometry().left()
        WinTop   = self.geometry().top()
        WinWidth = self.geometry().width()
        WinHight = self.geometry().height()
        ScrWidth = self.MnDskTop.screenGeometry().width()

      # Docking
        if Docking:
            if ScrWidth < (WinLeft + WinWidth + DockWdth):
                WinLeft  = 0
                WinWidth = ScrWidth
            elif WinLeft > (trunc(DockWdth/2)):
                WinLeft = WinLeft - trunc(DockWdth/2)
                WinWidth = WinWidth + DockWdth
            else:
                WinLeft = 0
                WinWidth = WinWidth + DockWdth

            self.setGeometry(WinLeft, WinTop, WinWidth, WinHight)
     # Un-Docking
        else:
            WinWidth = WinWidth - DockWdth
            self.setGeometry(WinLeft, WinTop, WinWidth, WinHight)
          # Call the Event that Triggers View Adjustment ?? 
            self.CenterPane.ItemDsply.updateGeometry()
#            self.CenterPane.ItemDsply.resizeEvent(QResizeEvent(self.size(), QSize()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp = QApplication([])

    MainGui = UI_MainWindow(MainApp.desktop())
    MainGui.show()

    sysExit(MainApp.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: No this breaks the example and does not fix the problem.  Column 1 is meant to have the Stretch applied to not Column 3 --- and considering that the right side of the window is still chopped off which gets resolved if a tweak the size of the main window just a smidge confirms this.